# Jquery Carousel not working (Issue with JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below link of the slider which I created using JS fiddle is not working. Please help

[Slider link](http://jsfiddle.net/HHsxc/2/)

```
 <div class="row">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical">
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&text=First+Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&text=Second+Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&text=Third+Slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/nxdmracz/)

The external resources which you have linked was giving error.

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 3000
})
```

for cdn use `maxcdn`

Comment: just changed the external urls

Comment: external urls means, i did not got you